# Connecting ArcSDE geodatabse 10 from ArcSDE service Version 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase

I have recently upgraded ArcSDE Geodatabse from 9.3 to 10.0.
The applications were using SDE connection through ArcSDE Windows service V 9.3

Now when I tried starting the same ArcSDE windows service on same instance and for same oracle database using following command - >>
sdemon -o start -i sde_pumaqa2 -p sde

**This is giving following error -**
sde_pumaqa2 service failed during initialization.
Please check event log or error log files.
Error starting sde_pumaqa2 service(0)
Could not start ArcSDE -- Check Network, $SDEHOME disk, DBMS settings and dbinit
.sde.

---

**The event viewer shows following error -** 
The description for Event ID 110 from source sde_pumaqa2 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

sde_pumaqa2
Connection to RDBMS failed

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

---

There was no change is any of the dbinit / driver file. They are checked and confirmed.
Please let me know if any step I am missing in this upgrade process.

Comment: Can you confirm that you upgraded to 10.0 -- ten-point-o? That version has been retired for quite some time, as such you might have a hard time finding help.

Comment: The plan is to upgrade applications from 10.0 to 10.6, but the ArcSDE Geodatabase was still on 9.3.
So to take it to any version beyond 10.0 I had to upgrade it to 10.0 first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *can't* upgrade from 10.0 to 10.6.  You probably need an intermediate upgrade through 10.3 or so (which would move you into the realm of non-retired software). Unfortunately, it's been aeons since most others have messed with 9.3 to 10.0 upgrade, so you've lost a significant volume of knowledge. You'll need to follow the instructions carefully.  It's difficult to tell from your description, but you may have missed the step where the geodatabase upgrade was to be performed.  A 10.0 server will not start in a 9.3 database.